# Uso de "concernidos"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, conjugación

Hoy he escuchado la siguiente frase:

> "Estamos muy **concernidos** por..."

Es la primera vez que escucho el verbo concernir usado y conjugado de esta manera, siempre se usa como "me/nos concierne..."

¿Es correcto el uso de "concernidos" fuera de la tercera persona?

Edito: La frase completa es: "en la creación de empleo todos estamos muy concernidos..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La [Fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/) dice justo sobre el mismo caso por el que preguntaba que [es correcto](http://twitter.com/Fundeu/status/202676710557233152):

> Con el sentido de "afectar" sería apropiado: estamos muy afectados...

Answer (score 5):

Según he encontrado [en el DRAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=concernir), es un verbo defectivo, es decir, no se usa en todos los tiempos, modos o personas. El verbo concernir es defectivo porque solo puede ser usado infinitivo, en gerundio, en participio y en 3.ª persona.

En este caso, "concernidos" es participio (pasivo), así que en principio sí que podría usarse de esta manera, por lo que la oración estaría correcta.

Comment: But it is quite unusual ...

Comment: @belisarius Ya, nunca lo había oído hasta ahora, por eso pensaba que hasta estaba mal dicho. Haciendo una búsqueda sí que aparece en algunos diarios en España, tanto por citas como por propia redacción.

Answer (score 1):

## Español

La frase que estás analizando usa **concernido** como un adjetivo. Tal adjetivo no existe **oficialmente** en el idioma español.

Creo que usar **concernir** para tratar de decir **estar preocupado** es simplemente una muy mala traducción del inglés:

> **I'm concerned** about the current state of affairs.
> **Me preocupa** el estado actual de las cosas.

Si analizamos esa oración respecto de **concernido** como un participio pasado, entonces de acuerdo al [DRAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=concernir) (tal como fue citado por @JoulSauron), no existe un significado para esta palabra relacionado con **preocupar** que pudiere hacer el enlace necesario para poder usar el participio pasado del primer verbo de la misma manera que se hace con el segundo.

Ahora bien, si se quiere dar la idea de que el sujeto de la frase está **involucrado** en aquello de lo cual está hablando, entonces el concepto asociado al verbo está bien usado, pero están creando un adjetivo que no existe —lo que no es algo malo por cierto— pero que puede dar pie a malos entendidos mientras aquel significado no sea asimilado por las demás personas.

---

## English

The sentence you are analizing uses **concernido** as an adjective. Such an adjective doesn't *officialy* exist in Spanish.

I think that using **concernir** to mean **estar preocupado** is just a very bad translation from English:

> **I'm concerned** about the current state of affairs.
> **Me preocupa** el estado actual de las cosas.

If we analize that sentence regarding **concernido** as a past participle, and according to [DRAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=concernir) (as cited by @JoulSauron), there's no meaning for **concernir** related to **preocupar**, what could make the link to use the past participle of the first verb the same way the second one.

But, if the subject of the phrase wants to mean he/she is **involved** in the main matter that's being referred, then the idea behind the verb (**concernir**) is well used, but they are inventing a yet non existent adjective (something not too bad by the way) but that may lead to misunderstandings as long as that new meaning is not properly assimilated by the people.

Comment: No sé por qué lo relacionas con el inglés, no tiene nada que ver con lo que preguntaba, simplemente piensa que se está usando concernido por su signifado. La frase la dijo la vicepresidenta de España en unas declaraciones ante los medios de comunicación.

Comment: Lo relaciono con el inglés porque como la frase está totalmente extraída de su contexto (no está la oración entera ni la cita desde donde fue extraída), y como esa palabra no existe, es más directo pensar de ella que es un "falso amigo" que viene del inglés (ejemplo clásico decir "asumir" en vez de "suponer").

Comment: Ya, lo pensé en su momento un poco, pero lo descarté porque aunque fuera un calco del inglés, puede estar bien dicho o no. La frase completa es: "en la creación de empleo todos estamos muy concernidos...", queriendo decir que están implicados e interesados.

Comment: El problema principal es que como aquella palabra no existe oficialmente, sólo nos queda especular sobre su significado. Con el contexto que me acabas de dar, ambas suposiciones (viene del verbo español `concernir` o es un falso amigo del inglés `concerned`) pueden ser válidas.

Comment: Sí que existe, es participio de concernir, ese es el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Leyendo la frase original:

> en la creación de empleo todos estamos muy concernidos...

Entiendo el sentido de "concernir" tal como se describe un poco más arriba, es decir con el sentido de "involucrar".

Usar "afectado", "consternado" u otro "preocupado" sería modificar el sentido de la frase original.

En mi opinión, "todos estamos involucrados en la creación de empleo", tiene mucho más sentido, y para apoyar mi argumentación les comento que traducido al francés no queda ninguna duda ya que usamos este participio pasado en forma pasiva como adjetivo muy a menudo "*concernés*" y con este exacto sentido.

Origen latina: *concernere*

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! Por favor, no uses el estilo código fuente aquí, eso es para código, como en Stack Overflow. En español se usan comillas. Esperamos verte por aquí a menudo. :)

Comment: quedó entendido, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la explicación es mucho más simple:

Los políticos, por desgracia y a pesar de lo que algunos puedan pensar, no saben hablar bien. Es un hecho.

Con toda probabilidad lo que quería decir era "consternados". Lo que es más preocupante es que no todo el mundo se dé cuenta, como tú, de que no tiene sentido lo que dicen.

Para quien piense que no es cierto, que hablan correctamente, fijaos en cómo usan (en españa) el "deber" o "deber de". El primero es de obligación, el segundo es de suposición. Pues bien, fiajos y comprobaréis que 10 de cada 10 veces lo usan mal. Sólo fijaos.

Otra posible explicación es que lo hagan a propósito para que nos fijemos más en el despiste que en la situación del país...

Me viene a la mente cierto "despiste" de nuestro ex-presidente, cuando dijo que debíamos ir a Rusia a "follar" en lugar de "apoyar"... ¿Despiste? A mí me parece exagerado. Por sus caras, a los diplomáticos rusos, cuando les hacen la traducción simultánea, también :)

(y justo después dice que el paro está peor que nunca)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTxwpcFk9YI&feature=fvwrel

--

I think the explanation is much simpler:

Politicians, unfortunately and despite what some may think, do not speak well. It's a fact.

In all probability what he meant was "shocked/worried" (consternados). What is more worrying is that not everyone is aware, like you, that what they say makes no sense.

For those who think that it is true that politicians speak correctly, look at how they use (in spanish) "deber" or "deber de". The first indicates obligation, the second assumption. Well, look at it and you will see that 10 out of 10 times it's misused. Just look it for yourself.

Another possible explanation is that they do it on purpose so that we look more at fault than at the situation in the country ...

It comes to my mind a ""fail"" of our former president, saying we should go to Russia to "fuck" instead of "support" ... A fail? It seems to me too exaggerated. On their faces, the Russian diplomats, when they ear simultaneous translation, show how the fail is too much ;)

(just after this, he says the unemployment is worse than ever)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTxwpcFk9YI&feature=fvwrel

Comment: No creo que porque los políticos hablen mal y cometan errores muchas veces signifique la frase esté bien dicha o no. ¿Sabes si "concernidos" es correcto o no? ;)

Comment: Creo que la frase tal como está comentada en su contexto original tiene perfecto sentido (el de `involucrado`) y no requiere substituición ninguna por `consternado`.

Answer (score 0):

Concernido, como tal, no existe en el diccionario de la real academia española [haz clic aquí](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=concernido) para ver.

Pero generalmente es usada de acuerdo al contexto, el más común, es preocupado.

Ahora, concernir significa atañer, afectar, interesar... puedes ver el detalle [aquí](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=concernido)

Comment: Las conjugaciones de verbos nunca aparecen en un diccionario. Por ejemplo, "preocupado" no aparece en el diccionario, pero eso no significa que sea incorrecto.

Comment: el sentido aquí no tiene nada que ver con lo de estar preocupado, pero mas bien con el de estar involucrado

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo con JoulSauron en que "concernido" existe y es correcto, aunque el uso en la frase de la pregunta, con el sentido más bien de "preocupado", no es habitual y parece un anglicismo, como dice Nicolás. El sentido habitual de "concernir" es "atañer, incumbir": si algo no te afecta o no tiene que ver contigo, entonces no te concierne y tú no te sientes concernido.

No estoy de acuerdo con Nicolás y Luis Sánchez, que dicen que "concernido" no existe, en primer lugar porque **las palabras existen si se usan, estén o no en los diccionarios**, y en segundo lugar, porque ni el DRAE ni ningún otro diccionario recoge todas las palabras que se pueden formar por derivación.

"Concernido" está bien formado a partir de "concernir", existe y se usa, y la pretensión de zanjar este o cualquier otro debate con el argumento de que "esa palabra no existe porque no está en el diccionario" es, con todo respeto, una solemne tontería.

El mundo hispanohablante es vasto, de forma que lo máximo que un hablante individual puede afirmar de una palabra es que no la conoce o no la ha visto nunca.

No olvidemos que decenas de miles de términos técnicos muy correctos de todas las materias y especialidades están ausentes de todos los diccionarios generales.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rae.es/dpd/concernir

Vemos aquí la explicación en el "Diccionario panhispánico de dudas" (DPD) de la RAE. No deberíamos usar "concernidos" en ese tipo de expresiones. Al tratarse realmente de un verbo intransitivo, no es correcto el uso del participio pasivo ("concernido, concernida, concernidos, concernidas"). Si hay voz pasiva en un verbo es porque es transitivo. La existencia del participio "concernido" no es como adjetivo (en cuyo caso estaría en la voz pasiva del verbo), sino como participio invariable en género y número, usado solo para la formación de los verbos compuestos.

Comment: Tal como yo lo entiendo, el punto 3 del link dice que el uso transitivo es correcto, pero no recomendable. La [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/concernido-2395/) también lo interpreta así.